# iPad(ios9.2)におけるons-pull-hookの挙動

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

Monacaで作成したアプリで挙動がおかしくなりました。

iPad(ios9.1)の頃は滑らかに動いていたアプリが、ios9.2にアップデートしたあたりでons-pull-hookを使用しているリストのスクロールがガクガクするようになりました。

Onsen UIのバージョンは1.3.0です。
・上下のスワイプでリストをスクロールさせ、スクロール中に再度上下のスワイプを行うと、ほぼスクロール直前の位置に戻り、そこから再度スクロールを行っているように見える。
・スクロールが止まった状態で上下スワイプを行うとスクロールされる。
・スワイプではないスクロールは通常通りスクロールできる。

慣性でスクロール中に操作を行うと、挙動がおかしくなるようです。

また、iPhoneでは普通に動いているように感じられます。

同様の現象が起きた方や解決法をご存知の方はいらっしゃいますでしょうか？

Comment: `Onsen UI 1.3.14`がリリースされていますので、まずはアップデート後にその挙動が発生しないか確認した方が早いと思います。ページの下の方にリリースノートがありますので、そちらも参照した方がよろしいかと思います。  http://ja.onsen.io/download.html

Comment: ありがとうございます。
Onsen UIのアップデートは失念しておりました。
アップデートして動作確認を行いましたが、解消されませんでした・・・。